# Adding UIScrollView to table cell seems to affect table scroll performance

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, rubymotion

I'm not sure this was poor implementation or a poor decision to start with, but I'm attempting to add a horizontal UIScrollView inside of each cell within my UITableView. I add it is as a subview to the cell's contentView, then call cell.clipsToBounds = true (FYI, I'm using RubyMotion). When I tap a button on the cell, I use `beginUpdates/endUpdates` to trigger `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to expand the cell's height and show the "hidden" scrollview.

Anyway, since doing that my table's scroll is a bit sluggish. I've added my code below and am wondering if my implementation can be improved to fix that scroll performance. Any help/insight is helpful (though if possible I'd like to try and keep the scroll views).

```
my_array = [
  ["Hi", "there", "one"],
  ["Hi", "there", "two"],
  ["Hi", "there", "three"],
  ["Hi", "there", "four"],
]

scroll_frame = CGRectMake(
    0, rowHeight - 1, hidden_width, 51
  )
hidden_scroll = UIScrollView.alloc.initWithFrame(scroll_frame)
hidden_scroll.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
hidden_scroll.bounces = true
hidden_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(hidden_width * my_array.size, scroll_frame.size.height)
hidden_scroll.delegate = parent
hidden_scroll.clipsToBounds = true
hidden_scroll.pagingEnabled = true
hidden_scroll.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
hidden_scroll.layer.borderWidth  = 1
hidden_scroll.layer.borderColor  = UIColor.colorWithRed(200.0/255, green:200.0/255, blue:200.0/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
hidden_scroll.backgroundColor  = UIColor.colorWithRed(248.0/255, green:248.0/255, blue:248.0/255, alpha: 1)
hidden_scroll.scrollEnabled = false

my_array.each_with_index do |data, index|
  hidden_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame(CGRectMake(
      (parent.view.frame.size.width * index), 0, parent.view.frame.size.width, 50
    )
  )

  label_frame           = CGRectMake(
    40, 5, (parent.view.frame.size.width - 40 - 7) * 2/3, 40
  )
  label                 = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame(label_frame)
  label.font            = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(11)
  label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
  label.text            = data[0]
  label.numberOfLines   = 0
  label.lineBreakMode   = UILineBreakModeWordWrap
  label_size            = data[0].sizeWithFont(label.font)
  label.sizeToFit
  new_frame             = label.frame
  new_frame.origin.y    = (50 - label.frame.size.height) / 2
  new_frame.size.height = label.frame.size.height
  label.frame           = new_frame

  button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeCustom)
  button.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor
  button.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11)
  button.setTitle(data[3].upcase, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
  button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor, forState:UIControlStateNormal)
  button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
  button.instance_variable_set(:@data, data)
  button_size = data[3].upcase.sizeWithFont(button.font)
  button.frame = [
    [label.frame.origin.x + label_frame.size.width + 5, (50 - label_size.height) / 2 - 3],
    [80, button_size.height + 6]
  ]

  button.addTarget(parent, action:"add_user_goal:", forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

  hidden_view.addSubview(label)
  hidden_view.addSubview(button)

  hidden_scroll.insertSubview(hidden_view, belowSubview: cell.contentView)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the UIScrollView isn't in view anyway, try creating the UIScrollView *only* when the user taps the cell to view it. Before then, there's just an empty area of the cell.

For cleaner code, I'd also recommend subclassing UIScrollView and doing your customization in a custom initializer.

```
class CellScrollView < UIScrollView
  def initWithCustom(args={})
    self.initWithFrame(args[:frame])

    # ... all your customizations. Use the args hash to pass in any other data you need.

    self
  end
end
```